# MongoDB Insert Error

Tags: mongodb, haskell, insert

I'm getting an error on what looks like a basic insert. The relevant code is

```
newConn = runIOE $ connect $ host "127.0.0.1"
run pipe act = access pipe master "MyDB" act

newRecord :: Pipe -> Value -> Value -> IO (Either Failure Value)
newRecord pipe fname lname = run pipe $ insert "people" ["name" := fname, "lastName" := lname]
```

When I hop into GHCi and run

```
:set -XOverloadedStrings
pipe <- newConn
newRecord pipe "Inai" "mathi"
```

I get the error

```
<interactive>:95:16:
    No instance for (Data.String.IsString Database.MongoDB.Value)
      arising from the literal `"Inai"'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (Data.String.IsString Database.MongoDB.Value)
    In the second argument of `newRecord', namely `"Inai"'
    In the expression: newRecord pipe "Inai" "mathi"
    In an equation for `it': it = newRecord pipe "Inai" "mathi"
```

According to [this](https://github.com/TonyGen/mongoDB-haskell/blob/master/doc/tutorial.md) and [this](https://github.com/TonyGen/mongoDB-haskell/blob/master/doc/Example.hs), unless I'm missing something, that should have worked.

Any hints?

Comment: could you show the type of `newRecord`? You're running into a problem with the `OverloadedString` extension, which uses the `IsString` class.

Comment: @ChrisDueck - Done. Though I should mention: none of the MongoDB docs or examples declare types, and those still seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefully at the two links you're mentioning. The Haskell MongoDB bindings provide two operators that look very similar:

```
(:=) :: Label -> Value -> Field
(=:) :: Val v => Label -> v -> Field
```

The second form is overloaded and more flexible to use. Anything that is in the `Val` class, and this includes `String`s, can be passed as the second argument. So you probably want to change the occurrences of `:=` in `newRecord` by `=:` (*and* adapt the type signature accordingly). Then your example will work.

Comment: Yup. Changing the type signature to `newAccount :: Val v => Pipe -> v -> v -> IO (Either Failure Value)` and changing out `:=` for `=:` gets this working.

Answer (score 1):

newRecord expects `fname` and `lname` to have type `Value`. You're passing in two overloaded `String`s, but GHC cant find an instance of `IsString` for `Value` to convert those overloaded `String`s to `Value`s.

I see that `Value` has a constructor `String :: Text -> Value`, see if this compiles:

```
newRecord :: Pipe -> Text -> Text -> IO (Either Failure Value)
newRecord pipe fname lname = run pipe $ insert "people" ["name" := String fname, "lastName" := String lname]
```

Comment: This works, but I'm going to go with kosmikus answer in this particular case because I don't otherwise import `Data.Text`.